# The target type of this expression should be a functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Below piece of code gives me a compilation error at

```
.filter(Book::getPrice >200)
```

> Compilation error is: 
>   The target type of this expression should be a functional interface

```
public void skipData() {
    List<Book> bookList = books.stream()
                                **.filter(Book::getPrice >200)**
                                .skip(5)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

My Book.java class looks as follows :

```
public final class Book {

private String title;
private String genre;
private double price;

public Book(String title, String genre, double price) { 
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.price = price;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

//other getters
}
```

I tried to run this on Eclipse (Mars) and also on the cmd line & saw the same problem.

But if i change it to `.filter(b -> b.getPrice() >200)` it works.

It's not clear for me why the method reference doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What is the declaration of variable `books`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Book::getPrice > 200` is not a valid Java expression.

Any method that can take a lambda expression as a parameter, can take *one* of the following:

- A lambda expression: `b -> b.getPrice() > 200`
- A lambda block: `b -> { return b.getPrice() > 200; }`
- A method reference: `Book::isPriceAbove200`
- An anonymous class: `new Predicate<Book>() { public boolean test(Book b) { return b.getPrice() > 200; }}`

A method reference allows reuse of a method.

Answer (score 0):

The filter method uses a function that takes a single argument and returns a boolean to determine whether to accept elements or to filter them out.

`Book::getPrice >200` is not a function of any kind. It is not even a `boolean` since you are comparing a method reference to an integer, resulting in trash.

`b -> b.getPrice() >200` is a function (lambda) that accepts the element of the stream you are filtering (`b`) and checks if that particular element's price is acceptable.